# upload text & image with a form and storing it in a path & database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been trying to store an image in the database,but it doesn't work. It does work with text, but not with image uploading.

When I click on submit it does nothing but refresh the same page. I can store text in the database if I don't use the image codes (afbeelding).

What did I do wrong? please help

This is the PHP

```
<?php

include("connect.php");


if(isset($_POST['titel']) && isset($_POST['content']) && isset($_POST['afbeelding'])){

    $titel = $_POST['titel'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $afbeelding = $_POST['afbeelding'];

    $tmp = $_FILES['afbeelding']['tmp_name'];
    $file_location = 'gallery/'.date("YmdHis").'_'.$_FILES['afbeelding']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tmp, $file_location);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `portfolio_items` (titel, content, date, afbeelding, active) VALUES (:titel, :content, NOW(), :afbeelding, 1)";

    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':titel', $titel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':content', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':afbeelding', $afbeelding, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

    echo "Opgeslagen!";

}
```

This is the form

```
<form method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="verzonden" value="1" />
        <input type="text" name="titel" required placeholder="Titel" maxlength="20">
        <br>
        <textarea rows="13" cols="30" required name="content" placeholder="Content" id="tekst" maxlength="400"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="file" id="afbeelding" accept="image/jpeg, image/x-png, image/gif" required>
        <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Opslaan">
</form>
```

Sorry for my messy English, it's not my native language

Comment: add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag

Comment: And, really - storing images in the database? Why not just store the images on the file-system, with a link to where it is stored in the database (or just the image name, really, since the file-system logic can just as well be done on the web-server)

Comment: Sorry, I mean storing the path to the image in the database

Answer (score 0):

some line changes in your code see below:

```
<?php

include("connect.php");


if(isset($_POST['titel']) && isset($_POST['content']) && isset($_FILES['afbeelding'])){

$titel = $_POST['titel'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

$tmp = $_FILES['afbeelding']['tmp_name'];
$file_location = 'gallery/'.date("YmdHis").'_'.$_FILES['afbeelding']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tmp, $file_location);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `portfolio_items` (titel, content, date, afbeelding, active) VALUES (:titel, :content, NOW(), :afbeelding, 1)";


$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':titel', $titel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':content', $content, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':afbeelding', $_FILES['afbeelding']['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

echo "Opgeslagen!";

}
```

FORM CODE

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="verzonden" value="1" />
        <input type="text" name="titel" required placeholder="Titel" maxlength="20">
        <br>
        <textarea rows="13" cols="30" required name="content" placeholder="Content" id="tekst" maxlength="400"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="file" id="afbeelding" name="afbeelding" accept="image/jpeg, image/x-png, image/gif" required>
        <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Opslaan">
    </form>
```

Comment: It would be more obvious what you changed if you would just display that part.

Comment: It still doesn't work, the file doesn't get uploaded to 'gallery/' and it doesn't save anything in the database